# Is it possible to run a WindowsCE executable to Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile, exe, windows-ce, portable-executable

This are many applications, some are very simple while other make use of other libraries.

Comment: If the processor matches it should normally run. But Windows CE is not a standard, OEMs can decide what to include. Windows Mobile 5/6 is based on CE 5 and adds aygshell and is a standard. The other way around will mostly not work for missing dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It depends.

First off, Windows Mobile only runs on ARM, whereas Windows CE is available for a number of CPU architectures, including ARM, x86 and MIPS. So the CE executable would have to be built for ARM.

That aside, you would need to look at the libraries, or components, that the CE executable depends on. Windows Mobile includes only a subset of the components that Windows CE provides, so if the CE executable depends on a component that does not exist in Windows Mobile, it will not run.

The `dumpbin` utility included with Visual Studio can show you all the function imports (and, thus, all the static dependencies), however this can be extremely time-consuming to go through for a complex application. Also bear in mind that even if all these dependencies are satisfied, the application might still be making other assumptions that are not met on Windows Mobile.

If you control the source code, probably the easiest way to ensure that a Windows CE application will also run on Windows Mobile is to build it against one of the SDK's provided by Microsoft - depending on the version you are targeting, look for e.g. *Windows Mobile SDK* or *Pocket PC SDK*.

Without access to the source code, and if the product documentation doesn't specify anything, I would say the most practical way to find out if a given CE executable runs on Windows Mobile is simply to try.

Answer (score 0):

> So the CE executable would have to be built for ARM

I think it's not always wise for "experiance" useres to choose ARM.

> Windows Mobile includes only a subset of the components that Windows CE provides, so if the CE executable depends on a component that does not exist in Windows Mobile, it will not run.

[Look here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_CE#Relationship%5Fto%5FWindows%5FMobile.2C%5FPocket%5FPC.2C%5Fand%5FSmartPhone)